# use nanoc for github pages

Tags: git, github, nanoc

I tried using `nanoc` for generating a static blog on github pages.
I found several tutorial and blogposts about it but they all seem out-dated and not working.

This is what I did:

1. Install nanoc into diretory `/MYNAME.github.io`
2. compile the default static site by executing `nanoc`
3. create a Github repository called `MYNAME.github.io`
4. in my directory I execute the following commands:

   git init

   git add .

   git commit -m "initial commit"

   git remote add origin https://github.com/MYNAME/MYNAME.github.io.git

   git push -u origin master

then all files in this directory will be uploaded to the repository.

However, I only get a 404 error when I go to **http://MYNAME.github.io** .
But, I see the start page when I got to **http://MYNAME.github.io/output/** .

Am I supposed to push only the *output* directory ?

Also, the start page is really ugly compared to when I run the nanoc server locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I supposed to push only the output directory ?

Yes. Or rather only the *contents* of the `output` directory, which means running `git init` from within that folder instead of the top-level folder of your nanoc site.

> Also, the start page is really ugly compared to when I run the nanoc server locally.

This is most likely because your page refers to a stylesheet at (say) `/css/default.css`, but because of how you've configured the git repository the stylesheet is actually available only at  `/output/css/default.css`. Fix the first problem and this problem should go away as well.